# JavaScript - How to get current date, and store previous dates, for use in a list?

Tags: javascript, date, variables

I would like to make a UL with previous dates, the current date, and have 
these listed items nested within it. An example is this:

```
•   Monday November 13, 2017
   o    List item
   o    List item
   o    List item
•   Tuesday November 14, 2017
   o    List item
   o    List item
   o    List item
•   Wednesday November 15, 2017
   o    List item
   o    List item
   o    List item
```

I would be getting the current date via JavaScript.

How would I be able to do the following?

1. Get the current date via JavaScript?
2. Store the previous dates (i.e. yesterday's date, the day before's date, etc.)?;

note: every time a new list item is added (like a to do app), the current date will be saved. If i were to come back to my app the next day, yesterday's date is saved, and the current date is added. Hope that makes sense!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) `new Date()` or `Date.now()` 2) `today - 1000*60*60*24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply following code.

```
var todayDate = new Date();
var yesterdayDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var beforeDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 2 * ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
 console.log("Today Date: " + todayDate );
 console.log("yesterday Date: " + yesterdayDate );
 console.log("before Date: " + beforeDate );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('mylist');

var daysAmount = 3;
var items = [
  {v: 'v1'},
  {v: 'v2'},
  {v: 'v3'},
];

var ts = new Date() / 1;
  
for(var i = daysAmount; i >= 0; i--){ // 3 previous + today = 4 days on list
  var shift = i * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  
  var previousDay = new Date(ts - shift);
  
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var nestedUl = document.createElement('ul');
  items.forEach(function(el){
    var nestedLi = document.createElement('li');
    nestedLi.innerText = el.v;
    nestedUl.appendChild(nestedLi);
  });
  
  li.innerText = previousDay;
  li.appendChild(nestedUl);
  ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
</ul>
```